# Check convergence of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to check as for the convergence the sequence $(a^n b^{n^2})$ for all the possible values that $a,b$ take.

I have thought the following:

We have that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a^n=+\infty$ if $a>1$, $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a^n=0$ if $-1<a<1$, right?

What happens for $a<-1$ ?

For the $b$-term, we have the same as above. So we have to check all the possible combinations, right? How can we check the convergence of $(a^n b^{n^2})$ when we get an undefined form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product $a^nb^{n^2}$ can be rewritten as $(ab^n)^n$. Therefore, it suffices to discuss the value of $(ab^n)$.

First, we consider the sign of $ a$ and $b $.

(1) If $ab>0$, then $a^nb^{n^2}$ = $|a|^n|b|^{n^2}$.

(2) If $ab<0$, then the sign of $a^nb^{n^2}$ changes when $n$ increases by $1$.

$\qquad$Then $a^nb^{n^2}$ converges only when $|a|^n|b|^{n^2}\to 0$ .

Second, we may assume that $a>0,\ b>0$.

(1) When $b > 1$, $ab^n \to +\infty$, $(ab^n)^n\to +\infty$.

(2) When $b < 1$, $ab^n \to 0$, $(ab^n)^n\to 0$.

(3) When $b = 1$, $(ab^n)=a$, the convergenge of $(ab^n)^n$ equals the convergence of $a^n$.

Comment: I have some questions. At the first case, don't we also have to take into consideration if $a$ is positive or negative? If $a<0$, then $ab^n \to -\infty$, or not? Also we have that $(+\infty)^{+\infty}=+\infty$, right? What is $(-\infty)^{+\infty}$ equal to? Does the second case holds for all $b<1$ or just for $-1<b<1$ ? @WembleyInter

Comment: @Evinda Sorry for not discussing the sign of $a$ and $b$. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Again  I have a question. Can we consider  the general case $ab>0$ ? Because suppose that $a=-m_1, b=-m_2$ where $m_1,m_2>0$. Then $ab^n=((-m_1)(-m_2)^n)$. If $n$ is odd, $ab^n$ will have a different value than when $n$ is even :/

Comment: But when $ab>0$, we can come back to the original discussion of convergence of  $a^nb^{n^2}$, which remain the same whether $b>0$ or $b<0$.

Comment: I have two questions. First of all, by saying the following:

If $ab<0$, then the sign of $a^n b^{n^2}$ changes when $n$ increases by $1$.

$$$$

you mean that when $n$ is odd? $$$$

Secondly, why does it hold that $a^n b^{n^2}$ converges only when $|a|^n|b|^{n^2} \to 0$ ?

Comment: For the first question, I actually mean that when the parity of $n$ changes, the sign of $a^nb^{n^2}$ changes, which can be proved by $sgn(a^{n+1}b^{(n+1)^2})=sgn(a^nb^{n^2})*sgn(ab^{2n+1})=sgn(a^nb^{n^2})*sgn(ab)=-sgn(a^nb^{n^2})$.

Comment: For the second one, when $|a|^n|b|^{n^2} \to $some $l$ and $l\ne0$, since the sign of $a^nb^{n^2}$ changes when the parity of $n$ changes, the limit of $a^nb^{n^2}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You mean that $a^n b^{n^2}$ converges only if it converges for each possible combination of $ab$ to the same limit? And for $ab<0$, if for some $n$ it holds that $a^n b^{n^2}=|a|^n |b|^{n^2}$ then for $n+1$ we will have that  $a^{n+1} b^{(n+1)^2}=-|a|^{n} |b|^{n^2}$. So in oder $a^n b^{n^2}$ to converge it has to hold that $|a^n| |b|^{n^2}=-|a|^n |b|^{n^2} \Rightarrow |a|^n |b|^{n^2}=0$. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: Right. That's just what I mean.